# Delete blobs in Azure storage account except the lastest version using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, blob, versioning

We've disabled versioning for Azure storage account. We now have a lot of blobs with multiple versions in different containers and want to delete theb old versions of each blob.
I get a list of blobs with versions using powershell:

Get-AzStorageBlob -Container containerName -IncludeVersion

I see the lastest version of each blob is marked '*'.
I want to keep only the latest version of the blob in the container.
How I can delete all blobs in Azure storage account except the lastest version using powershell?

Comment: `Update-AzStorageBlobServiceProperty -ResourceGroupName $rgName  -StorageAccountName $accountName  -IsVersioningEnabled $false`

Comment: This cmdlet disables the versioning, but doesn't delete old blob versions.
I still see all versions of blobs in containers.

Answer (score 0):

> How I can delete all blobs in Azure storage account except the lastest version using powershell?

*Once you get the list of containers with the version below is the command you can use it for deleting the blob by using version.*

```
Remove-AzStorageBlob -Container "containername" -Blob blob2 -VersionId "<Version ID>"
```

*Here is the [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/remove-azstorageblob?view=azps-8.2.0#example-4-remove-a-single-blob-version) for your reference.*